# Wildfly 13: not able to use {} [] in query string of url

Tags: java, wildfly

Whenever i'm trying to use {} or [] in url query string getting bad request.

How i can enable this in wildfly?

eg: https://stackoverflow.com?someVar={}

Comment: Take look at this [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: can you please hit this https://stackoverflow.com?someVar={}... in my case its not working

Answer (score 3):

In JBoss 7.2, I had to edit the standalone.xml and make the following change to get it working:

```xml
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Note that I have added a new attribute called **allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true"**.

The -Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true didn't work.

Comment: Works also on JBoss 7.3

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration option in undertow, which allows special characters as umlauts, {}, etc in the URL.

The property is: `org.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL`, e.g.:

```
./bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i'did same thing but its not working

Answer (score 0):

> By “default **allow-unescaped-character-in-url**” is set to false and in
> general, should not be needed as most clients correctly encode
> characters.  Please take note that setting this to true can be
> considered as a security risk, as allowing non-standard characters can
> allow request smuggling attacks in some circumstances.

That being said, this issue can be resolved by following below steps:

- Login to your Widfly Admin console
- Navigate to **Configuration=>Subsystems/Subsystem=>web/Settings=>Server/Server=>default-server=>htpp-listener**
- Click Edit and set “**ALLOW UNESCAPED CHARACTERS IN URL**” to **True**
- Reload the application

Please refer to below image for more details

[WIDFLY ALLOW UNESCAPED CHARACTERS IN URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgeaC.jpg)